# Command Line - programmatically add/remove/rename BIND alias records?

Tags: linux, centos, automation, bind

For our local dev server, we routinely add and remove name alias records in our BIND/named server for our local network domain. I usually do this manually through Webmin, just out of convenience. But I do it so often it's annoying and I would imagine it could be automated.

Is there someway to do this easily from the command-line using bash scripts? Ultimately, I'm looking for a way to add, remove and rename name aliases to the server.

And I'm hoping for something a little better than grepping the bind config file and searching/replacing...

Comment: Setup dynamic updates, and update via nsupdate.  See: http://serverfault.com/questions/324741/how-do-you-setup-a-dns-server-in-order-to-be-able-to-add-records-on-the-fly

Comment: Never knew that tool existed. Thank you! If you want to properly answer below I'll give you credit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The method I generally use is to setup the zone for dynamic updates, and then use [nsupdate](http://linux.die.net/man/8/nsupdate).

I have provided more details in [this answer](https://serverfault.com/a/324751).