# Manage Microsoft DNS Records from Linux

Tags: linux, domain-name-system

Is there a utility that allows remote editing of records on a Microsoft DNS server FROM LINUX? I know you can edit the records using DNSCMD but that is only usable on Window, is there something similar to that?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how you setup your authentication/authorization there is the ability to use Dynamic DNS.  For example I have my puppet server calling nsupdate to update a particular DNS zone host on my Windows server.  In [another answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/324741/how-do-you-setup-a-dns-server-in-order-to-be-able-to-add-records-on-the-fly/324751#324751) I provided example usage of nsupdate.