# Openvpn failover setup - Routing to clients with static ips

Tags: linux, routing, openvpn, failover, static-ip

I have a setup with an openvpn server and many clients connected to it. All those clients have fixed ip addresses, derived from their certificate name.

Behind the openvpn server, I have a management server, that needs to connect to the clients (to monitor/perform some remote commands).

```
                 |-C1
                 |-C2
A -- VPN server -|
                 |-C3
                 |-C4
```

Server A can connect to C1-4 through the VPN, using fixed ips.

What I want to do is expand the setup to multiple VPN servers (to handle server outages, and spread the load), while still having a simple way for A to find any specific remote client.

```
                  |-C1
                  |-C2
--- VPN server 1 -|
|
A
|
--- VPN server 2 -|
                  |-C3
                  |-C4
```

I know how to configure the clients to pick one of the openvpn servers at random, what I don't know is how to manage ip allocation.

Should I keep a single subnet for the servers? In that case, how does A know behind which server an ip is?
Should I have one subnet per openvpn server? In that case, how does A know which IP address to contact?

I've looked a bit into dynamic routing systems, but I would have to manage one route per client ip, which seems very wrong... Another option would be to keep a DNS (or DNS-like) service updated with the mapping {client-name => current ip address}, but that seems complicated, and I'm not sure all our software stack can adapt to it.

How are this kind of failover setups usually handled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> a DNS (or DNS-like) service updated with the mapping {client-name => current ip address}

Handing this on the OpenVPN server(s) is relatively easy with a `--client-connect` script on the OpenVPN servers.  The client connect script is passed the IP address of the new connection.  You can then use that to [call nsupdate](https://serverfault.com/a/324751/984) to adjust your DNS records.

Here is an old script I have that logged the external address of the connecting client.  Which isn't what you want, but I am sure you can find the right variables if you review the `Environmental Variables` section of the man page.

```
#!/bin/sh

# expects variables like from openvpn
#common_name=server1.example.org
#trusted_ip=192.168.47.1

dnssrv="192.168.0.1"
zone="vpn.example.org"
ttl="7200"

record=`echo ${common_name} | sed -e 's/example.org/vpn.example.org/'`

echo "client-connect.sh ${common_name} ${trusted_ip} ${record}" | logger

(
 echo "server ${dnssrv}"
 echo "zone ${zone}"

 echo "update delete ${record} A"
 echo "update add ${record} ${ttl} A ${trusted_ip}"
 echo "send"
) | /usr/bin/nsupdate
```